# Using MS Access VBA to Submit an HTML Form

Tags: html, ms-access, vba

I have written the following form inside an Access Database form.

```
Function Submit_Web_Form()

Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

  ie.navigate "http://www.webstaurantstore.com/bakers-pride-bco-e2-cyclone-series-electric-convection-oven-double-deck/155BCOE2.html"

  ie.Visible = True

While ie.busy
   DoEvents
Wend

ie.Document.all("from").Value = "Add"
ie.Document.all("weight").Value = "0"
ie.Document.all("price").Value = "5400.00"
ie.Document.all("description").Value = "Bakers%20Pride%20BCO%2DE2%20Cyclone%20Series%20Electric%20Convection%20Oven%20Double%20Deck"
ie.Document.all("uom").Value = "Each"
ie.Document.all("shipping").Value = "C"
ie.Document.all("taxcode").Value = "Y"
ie.Document.all("mnbuy").Value = "1"
ie.Document.all("mxbuy").Value = "1"
ie.Document.all("suffix").Value = "Voltage"
ie.Document.all("group").Value = "Y"
ie.Document.all("item_number").Value = "155BCOE2    240/1"
ie.Document.all("qty").Value = "1"
ie.Document.Forms(0).submit

While ie.busy
   DoEvents
Wend

Set ie = Nothing

End Function
```

While the function does not produce any errors, but it does not submit the form. I need to automate adding products into the shopping cart.

Does anyone have any experience working with an web page through VBA?

Comment: Have an upvote for using MS Access and doing something this crazy with it. Does your form populate with the values you're setting in code ?

Comment: I think you should consider using the XMLHTTPRequest object instead. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963475/http-post-in-vba

Comment: To sh1rts: We have a national chain of restaurants and we constantly order large quantities of equipment. We basically have the entire website inside the Access Database and expedite locating the item of interest. The idea was to add it to the shopping cart through Access, then open up Explorer and complete the checkout. To answer your question, In the example, we simplified the code without using variables for values in an effort to test the idea and to trace where the problem might be.

Comment: To All: We suspect the line ie.Document.Forms(0).submit is not correct, but were not sure how it might read differently.

Comment: To HK1: Thank you for the lead using XMLHTTPRequest object, we will explore that option.

Comment: "We basically have the entire website inside the Access Database" - please tell me you have some plan to migrate this to something sensible ? I'm sure you've probably inherited this solution, but the words "national chain" "entire website" and "Access" don't belong in one sentence. Access is fine for small, single-user desktop database applications - but anyone trying to use it for anything else is eventually going to be in a world of pain. Good luck and I hope you find a fix for your immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the HTML Object Library. Please take a look at this article I wrote some time ago: [Access and the web HTML Object Library](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Access_and_the_web_HTML_Object_Library). If you decide to use this approach I can assist you further.

Regards